# How to find the GUID of a GPO given it's name?

Tags: vbscript, gpo

Does anyone know of a way to find the GUID of a specific GPO given its name using VBScript? I've seen a lot of examples to go from a GUID to a GPO, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an LDAP query that filters for a given display name. The `name` attribute of the GPO contains the GUID.

```
displayName = "..."

domain = GetObject("LDAP://rootDSE").Get("defaultNamingContext")

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
cn.Open "Active Directory Provider"

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT name " & _
                  "FROM 'LDAP://CN=Policies,CN=System," & domain & "' " & _
                  "WHERE objectClass = 'groupPolicyContainer' AND " & _
                  "displayName = '" & displayName & "'"

Set rs = cmd.Execute
Do Until rs.EOF
  WScript.Echo rs.Fields("name").Value
  rs.MoveNext
Loop
```